# Use a specified theme into my application

Tags: mfc

I am developping under MFC and i want to confgure the color of a CProgressBar.

I have a theme by which when i run my programme i have a nice progress bar, so my aim is to know how could I produce the same color schema when I use any other windows Theme?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-classing to create your own custom control. Sublcassed controls can change the default behavior, so by handling the paint events, you can provide the control your desired colors regardless of current theme.
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/progresscontrols/article.php/c2349/Enhanced-ProgressBar-Control-v11.htm
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7663/Status-Progress-Feedback
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775501(v=vs.85).aspx